# What are the requirements for getting "Fortune Strike"?

Tags: muramasa-the-demon-blade

After you win a battle in Muramasa: The Demon Blade, you'll get a list of rewards for things you did during the battle, like "Quick Draw Finish" for killing an enemy with a quick draw attack or "Completed Unscathed" for clearing the fight without taking any damage.

One that I get every now and then, but cannot figure out what it is, is "Fortune Strike". As far as I can tell, I haven't been able to find any consistent method of earning this one. It's not really worth much, but considering I can at least tell how I received the others, this one is just confounding me all the time. What are the requirements for receiving this bonus, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Fortune Strike occurs when you interrupt an enemy attack, causing them to flinch out of performing it.

I could be wrong.

Comment: I'll try this out over the weekend, then. Never thought about it as interrupting... since that generally does occur and not occur without me paying heed, it does make a sensible requirement.

Comment: copy/paste source for ["I believe that Fortune Strike occurs when you interrupt an enemy attack, causing them to flinch out of performing it"](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/943228-muramasa-the-demon-blade/51395976) :)

Comment: Ha. Believe it or not, I didn't copy + paste from that thread. Good find though: That thread might be better than my anecdotal experience.

Comment: I lent my copy of the game to one of my friends. He'll enjoy it immensely, I hope, but the consequence is that I am no longer able to test this (last weekend ended up being pretty busy). So it'll be some time before I can accept this, unless someone else manages to chime in with something more confident.

Comment: Yes, by the way, the game is still lent out. I'm too busy running an alchemy workshop to particularly pester the fellow to have it back, yet, haha. ♪